# YTD calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to do a different YTD calculation than the norm. Normally I would use AVG over calc in SQL as this is the easiest way of doing it.

```
AVG(Value) over (Partition by what ever columns Order by Period and what ever columns ROWS BETWEEN unbound preceding and CURRENT ROW)
```

They calculate it is follows:

- Jul YTD - Jul value * no days in month / no of days ytd
- Aug  YTD - (Jul value * no days in month + Aug value * no of days in month) / no of days ytd
- Sep YTD -  (Jul value * no days in month + Aug value * no of days in month + Sep Value * No of days in the month) / no of days ytd

The table will look something like this:

```
Month   Value
Jul      100
Aug      200
Sep      300
```

Result should be

```
Month   YTD Value 
Jul      100
Aug      150
Sep      198.91
```

Is their an easy way of doing this in SQL

Comment: Months is running down in a column as well as Value

Comment: I see @GordonLinoff around, so I don't even start to write an answer :)

Comment: @ThomasG there's often more than one way to solve a problem...

Comment: @Nick true, but Gordon is Gordon. And see below what happened in the meantime ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with the number of days in a month.  In your case:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(t.value * m.days) over (order by period) / 
        sum(m.days) over (order by period)
       ) as average
from t left join
     (select 'Jul' as mon, 31 as days union all
      select 'Aug' as mon, 31 as days union all
      select 'Sep' as mon, 30 as days
     ) m
     on t.mon = m.mon
```

Comment: I actually solved it also yesterday. Using the same logic. I calculated an YTD Days in your inner select query as i have 3 calcs that i need to do this on. So i ended up with Sum(value * days in month) over ( partition by all required columns and order by ) / YTD days. Thank you for the help tough. :)